# Magento 2.2 - Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).autocomplete is not a function

Tags: magento2, jquery, console, autocomplete

Jquery UI autocomplete is not working. Refer the attachment.

[image]

Please help me to sort out this.

Comment: please share link where you are facing this issue, most probably its due to conflict between two jquery files.

Comment: Implementing in my local server. No, there is no multiple jQuery on my Magento. Due to an extension the issue occurs, the extension is Instagram Shop from Magenest.